# Is it Good to have Hibernate and Jaxb annotation both on the same class

Tags: jaxb, hibernate-annotations

I m trying to build a rest easy service with hibernate. Is it Good to have Hibernate and Jaxb be annotation both on the same class. OR there should be two different classes one for hibernate data object with annotation and another similar class for rest request and response with jaxb annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, basically if you need extra transfer objects next to your entities.

If you don't, the structure of your tranfer data (JSON, XML, whatever) will be more or less dictated of how your entities are structured. You can achieve a lot with annotations but you'll still be somewhat bound. As a consequence of this, changes in the entities may need to be propagated to your outer interfaces. Basically, if you change your entities and/or your database schema, you may also need to change the structure of the JSON returned by your REST interface.

Having separate DTOs is safer in cases when you need to provide stability of your interfaces. The downside is that you'll need mapping code to convert between DTOs and entities.

From my experience, you can get away with just entities most of the time.

Comment: Thanks Lexicore. I m quite satisfied with your reply.